# Cross-domain tracking with multiple profiles

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I've been trying to figure out how cross-domain tracking interacts with multiple UA-numbers.

### Questions

- Does referral/source/medium information get passed from 1 domain to the other if we have 2 UA numbers and use `_link`?
- Is there a way to figure out which domain the data came from if we use 1 UA number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First dot: The answer is yes.

Site A URL after coming from an adword: https://site-a.com?utm_source=google&utm_medium=adword_1&utm_campaign=adwords

Initialization on site A:

```
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-1']);
    _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
    _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'sitea.com']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

The link:

```
<a href="https://otherdomain?utm_source=thisdomain&utm_medium=youbutton&utm_campaign=EpicCampaign" onclick="_gaq.push(['_link', 'https://otherdomain?utm_source=thisdomain&utm_medium=youbutton&utm_campaign=EpicCampaign']); return false;">Click Me</a>
```

The result is
A) if you came from an adword (or some other source with utm info) the data will be retained when the link clicked regardless of UA numbers/profiles etc.
B) if you just dropped into site_a directly some how, the source/medium information on site_b will reflect what the link says

Second dot: @Alex Amthor is right!

Answer (score 1):

First dot: not quite sure but I would assume: No, exit on the first, entry on the second domain, separate unique visitors.

Second dot: There's a "secondary dimension" in the content report which offers "Hostname" as a breakdown - probably what you're looking for.